# Why did Will's heart need to go into the dead man's chest?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest, at-worlds-end

> "It was not worth feeling what small, fleeting joy life brings. And so, him carve out him heart, lock it down in a chest, and hide the chest from the world."

Davy Jones locked his heart away in a chest because of his love for Calypso, and possibly because of their mutual betrayal.

Now, "*The Dutchman* must have a captain", so after stabbing Davy Jones' heart  — killing him — William Turner had to become the new captain of *The Flying Dutchman*.

**But why did his heart needed to be put in the chest?**

Comment: Well, everyone's heart has to be in their chest.  Makes sense for Will to keep his heart in a chest too.

Comment: I assume it's safer that way. To kill Davy Jones you had to have his heart, right? If I remember correctly he was basically invincible. The only way to cause him physical pain was through his heart. Same would apply to Will.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Answer on another community](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/64414/9382):

> **The heart had a [geis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geis) upon it - cast by Davy Jones**
>
> In a deleted scene from ***Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*** Davy Jones states to Governor Swann.
>
> > "Are you prepared for what comes after? When I carved that traitorous vessel from my body, I cast upon it a terrible geis. **If you stab my heart, yours must take its place**. The crew are not bound to me. They are bound to the Dutchman. And the Dutchman must have a captain. Will ye serve?"
>
> from about 6:25 in

Basically, there are two curses, not just one. The first curse was placed by Tia Dalma (Calypso) on Davy Jones: to sail the seas, ferrying the dead souls for ten years, then come on shore to be with her for 1 day.
The second curse (or geis) was placed by Davy Jones himself when he cut his heart out: if someone stabs his heart, that person's heart must replace it.

So that's the answer to question 'Why did Will's heart have to be cut out as well?'. But as to why it had to be placed in the chest specifically, it most likely didn't have to. He could have kept it in a cloth sack and it would probably have still worked, since Davy Jones himself has had his heart in a chest, a cloth sack (when Norrington gave it to Beckett), a jar of dirt (Jack Sparrow) and even just transported in a shirt pocket (Jack and Norrington). But the chest was secure and safe, which is why it was used as the vessel in the first place.